# Black screen when upgrading 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I will explain what I have done.

1. Booted my PC using a live-disk and upgraded my system.
2. First it booted normaly but i saw it was using nouveau and i would my nvidea drivers back.
3. Installed the drivers from xorg/eders and got a black screen and not able to run any tty.
4. I Booted with my old 12.10 kernel tried installed some things that may missed.
5. Yeah i got it boot, I rebooted it just for being sure and it also worked good.
6. Next morning when i boot my PC i got black screen an no my ubuntu seems to be death at all.

I simply not understand how a PC can change it configuration even when it is turned off??? Or is my GPU died?

Some information of my PC:
- toshiba sattelite 660
- GPU 350M

Comment: Okay, when you upgraded, did you reinstall? Or did you select the "Upgrade" option (assuming you used the installer)?

Comment: Upgrade option i don't wont to reinstall my programs back.

Comment: Enabled nouveau on the old kernel and booted with the new kernel. Now it passed the black screen. Installed nvidea 319 and now it seems good. The only thing i don't know is for how long. Can it be because an old ccsm is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your GPU is died.
Maybe the Nvidia drivers are not compatible to Ubuntu 13.04 yet. Why you don't use the Nouveau drivers. They are open-source and because that they are faster compatible to newer Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Ever tried to play minecraft using nouveau :D. But I have already fixed it. Now i am using nvidia 319 beta driver and it works. (313 works to but it is not reliable PC boots only 3/5).